# Integrate the given expression to find $f(1)$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

If $$f(x)=\int \frac {x^2}{(x^2+2)(1+\sqrt{x^2+1})}dx$$ and $f(0)=0$ , then find $f(1)$

I multiplied and divided by $\sqrt{x^2+1}-1$ but later got stuck at $\int \frac{\sqrt{x^2+1}}{x^2+2}.dx$ How to solve this integral. Could someone help me with this?

Comment: Please specify the integral bounds, as there is no $t$ in the integrand so integrating w.r.t. $x$, does not leave a function of $t$.

Comment: $$\int \frac{\sqrt{x^2+1}}{x^2+2}\,dx$$
$$x=\sinh u;\;dx=\cosh u\,du$$
$$\int \frac{\sqrt{\sinh^2 u+1}}{\sinh^2u+2}\,\cosh u\,du$$
$$\int\frac{\cosh^2 u}{\sinh^2u+2}=\int\frac{\cosh^2 u}{1+\cosh^2 u}\,du$$
$$...$$

Comment: @JamalS I added the $t$ because OP probably meant $$f(t)= C + \int^t_0 \frac {x^2}{(x^2+2)(1+\sqrt{x^2+1})}dx$$. Anyway I rolled back the edit, still it is wrong.

Comment: @JamalS It is $f(x)$. Could have been a typo/

Comment: it is $$\sinh ^{-1}(x)-\frac{\tanh ^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2} \sqrt{x^2+1}}\right)+\tan
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}{\sqrt{2}}+C$$

Answer (score 3):

$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^2\,dx}{(x^2+2)(1+\sqrt{1+x^2})}\stackrel{x\mapsto\sinh z}{=}\int_{0}^{\log(1+\sqrt{2})}\frac{\sinh^2(z)\cosh(z)\,dz}{(\sinh^2(z)+2)(1+\cosh z)} $$
equals, by the substitution $z=\log t$,
$$ \int_{1}^{1+\sqrt{2}}\frac{(1-t)^2 (1+t^2)}{t(1+6t^2+t^4)}\,dt $$
which can be computed by partial fraction decomposition. The roots of $t(1+6t^2+t^4)$ are given by $0$ and $\pm i(\sqrt{2}\pm 1)$ and $\int_{1}^{1+\sqrt{2}}\frac{dt}{t-\zeta}=\log\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{2}-\zeta}{1-\zeta}\right)$, hence by computing five residues and simplifying

$$ \int_{1}^{1+\sqrt{2}}\frac{(1-t)^2 (1+t^2)}{t(1+6t^2+t^4)}\,dt = \color{blue}{\log(1+\sqrt{2})-\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left[\text{arctanh}\tfrac{1}{2}+\arctan\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right]}.$$